# How to create custom CFRunLoopRef in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to create custom CFRunLoopRef in iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't create them. Instead, each thread has one associated with it, which you can get with `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()`. That run loop is going to be inactive on any secondary thread you spawn, so you must start it with `CFRunLoopRun()`, which will then block on that secondary thread until it is stopped or until all its timers/sources are unscheduled.